# How to restore the default stroke in the BasicStroke class?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I have a program where I defined a bunch of new dash patterns and made them strokes using the `BasicStroke` class. Than I used the 
`.setStroke()` method and made lines with my dash patterns. Now I want to be able to `setStroke()` back to the default dash pattern (a solid line). How do I do this?
Here is my code:

```
    float[] dash1 = {2f, 0f, 2f};
        float[] dash2 = {1f, 1f, 1f};
        float[] dash3 = {16f, 10f, 4f, 10f};
        float[] dash4 = {4f, 4f, 1f};

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.drawLine(20, 40, 250, 40);

        BasicStroke bs1 = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f, dash3, 0f);

        BasicStroke bs2 =new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f, dash3, 16f);

        BasicStroke bs3 = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f, dash3, 2f);

        BasicStroke bs4 = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1.0f, dash4, 2f);



        g2d.setStroke(bs1);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 80, 250, 80);

        g2d.setStroke(bs2);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 120, 250, 120);

        g2d.setStroke(bs3);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 160, 250, 160);

        g2d.setStroke(bs4);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 200, 250, 200);
```

Comment: Can't you just store Stroke returned by g2d.getStroke() and set it back in the end?

Comment: +StanislavL I dont understand what you mean by that. Could you just give me an example line of code?

Comment: @StanislavL My bad tagged you wrong (like youtube LOL) read above comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store it in a variable and access it later like @StanislavL said

```
    Stroke defaultStroke;

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    defaultStroke = g2d.getStroke();
    //
    //do your thing
    //
    //reset by
    g2d.setStroke(defaultStroke);
```

Comment: Depending on what it's the OP is doing, if they've created a copy of the original `Graphics` context, they could just call `g2d.dispose()` and create a new copy if they wanted to do something else

Comment: Okay thanks Madhan thats what I needed. @MadProgrammer thanks also, good to know for the future but for this specific program I want to keep the current copy.

Comment: You can accept it as answer as it solved your problem so that it will be helpful for other people not wasting thier time trying to answer your problem

Comment: Sorry @Madhan my bad completly. I thought I had accepted it but I must have forgotten. Taken care of now. Really sorry about that and thanks again for the answer!